# How to config Jhipster existing app to build with "ng build"?

Tags: angular, build, configuration, jhipster, angular-universal

Is it possible to add/change `angular.json` config in order to land/build Jhispter (Angular) app with `ng ...`?
And can you help me or show me the way to do it if it's possible ?

I want it because i want to add `nguniversal/express-engine` which asks me to have a `build` target when I'm running `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`

Jhipster v6.1.2 with Angular v8.0.0

Comment: JHipster does not use (yet) angular-cli build so adding dependencies with `ng add` cannot work. Please refer to your project README.md to learn how to add dependencies.

Comment: Hello ! What do you mean by not "YET" ? Are you working on this ? Find this project today : https://github.com/brydko/jhipster-universal, i'm gonna look at this. Thx for your time

Comment: There has been some work done but it's not complete, you should show your interest at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/10624